# Cannot use a custom document class with LyX

Tags: lyx, texlive, document-classes, acm

I am trying to use the [ACM SIG Proceedings](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates) document class for a LyX document. Basically following these instructions: [Using custom LaTeX document classes in LyX](http://stefaanlippens.net/customLaTeXclassesinLyX)

Step by step, here is what I do:

1. put `acm_proc_article-sp.cls` in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/tex/latex`
2. run `sudo texhash`
3. (`cat /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/ls-R | grep acm_proc` shows `acm_proc_article-sp.cls`)
4. create `acmsig.layout` (contents below) and put it in `~/.lyx/layouts`
5. reconfigure LyX
6. restart LyX
7. try to select `article (ACM SIG Proceedings)` from the list of available document classes - it does not show up

What am I doing wrong?

The contents of `acmsig.layout`:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[acm_proc_article-sp]{article (ACM SIG Proceedings)}

# Input general definitions
Input stdclass.inc

MaxCounter      Counter_Section

Style Section
    Align Center
    Font
        Shape SmallCaps
    EndFont
End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This layout already exists in LyX 2.1 (currently in beta) and there is also a template (go to `New > New from Template > ACM-SIGS`). They were added in [this commit](http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/01add2d5/lyxgit).

Do you happen to use Ubuntu? If so, it's very easy to use the latest stable version (and/or development version) without having to give up your current version. They can all be installed concurrently with no risk. To do this, see the instructions [here](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3):

If you have any suggestions for the template or layout, please send a patch to `lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org`

I'm not sure what went wrong with your manually adding a template. Your steps looked right to me from a quick look. Note that the webpage you referenced is from 2006. Help > Customization is a better (but more complicated) reference.

EDIT:
One final bit of (unsolicited) advice. You're using TeX Live 2012, which is no longer being updated. If you happen to be using Ubuntu, you might be interested in using [this script](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) to install TeX Live 2013.

Comment: I am on Mac OS X - not sure how to get LyX 2.1.

Comment: @clstaudt both http://www.lyx.org or googling "LyX 2.1 beta" and clicking on the first link gives you what you need to know. Here is a direct link for Mac: ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta1/LyX-2.1.0beta1+qt4-cocoa.dmg